# Maven Dependency Plugin, copyDependencies: 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified

Tags: maven, dependencies, copy, pom.xml

In a multiproject maven build there are several poms containing

```
<distributionManagement>
<status>deployed</status>
</distributionManagement>
```

causing a org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException.
I execute

```
mvn verify -DskipTests -PlibCheck -e
```

In the libCheck profile I first exectute Maven-Dependency-Plugin:copyPoms and after that my written mojo.

log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy-dependencies (default) on project MY-PROJECT: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13 [ERROR] : 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2 [ERROR] [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13 [ERROR] -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy-dependencies (default) on project MY-PROJECT: Some problems were encountered while p rocessing the POMs: [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.buildProjectFromArtifact (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.getDependencySets (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.CopyDependenciesMojo.doExecute (CopyDependenciesMojo.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.buildProjectFromArtifact (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.getDependencySets (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.CopyDependenciesMojo.doExecute (CopyDependenciesMojo.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2 [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 36, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException (DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.buildProjectFromArtifact (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.getDependencySets (AbstractDependencyFilterMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromDependencies.CopyDependenciesMojo.doExecute (CopyDependenciesMojo.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute (AbstractDependencyMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) [ERROR] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :MY-PROJECT
```

The build fails due to the error within the :copyDependencies step.
Is it possible to somehow ignore those errors?
For given reasons I cannot simply remove those tags from the dependencies poms.

Kind regards

Comment: What are the reasons you cannot remove those tags?

Comment: I would also ask why do you need copyDependencies goal within a build?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I dont feel well doing that because I would have to deploy the relating poms to our nexus again and fear inconsistend states.
In the end, perhaps that may be the way to resolve this, though Id prefer a programmatical way around that in setting up the Dependency plugin in the pom somehow different.

Comment: @khmarbaise
Well, in short, we want to replace the source for information about our dependencies from external (whitesource) to internal, by first gathering the dependencies we use through first collecting poms, then parsing and indexing the dependencies, then creating a json with the infos and eventually shipping the json to the customers.

Comment: @pikkuez I would not replace POMs, but remove them for the next version.